# Web Apps, Site Collections and Webs

Tags: site-collection, administration

in our organisation we use wss 3.0 for out intranet. SharePoint usage has grown in recent months and the intranet itself is great. It consists of:
1 WFE;
1 SQL;
1 WebApp;
1 Root Site Collection;

We recently created a template site to be used for each of our projects (in the last month 28 project sites have been created).

My personal opinion is that these sites should not be created in the root site collection but instead put into there own site collection for example sites/projects1/ and then site/projects2, gradually creating new site collections are they fill-up.

Could any one recommend or suggest the best configuration for this?

Answer (score 2):

So there are some questions you have to ask.  First, with WSS 3 you can't aggregate data across site collections without custom development.  So if one collection you need to roll up data from another site collection, this will be difficult.  Same applies for content types.  You can't share content types across collections.  Site Collections allow you to set quotas at the collection level.  So each collection you create will have its own set of governance as it realtes to permissions, site collection admins quotas etc.  A nice thing about site collections is that you can create separate content databases for each collection.  You can't account for this with sites.

My feeling is that if you can do with out the data aggregation between collections go with site collections.  Or at least think about creating some additional top level site collections.

Paul

Comment: Yes, I'd go with a new managed path, /projects/ and create a root site there.  Then use a template to create subsites for each project within it.  Or create a projects web application.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. You both have the same approach that I was thinking I should take. I can live without data aggregation and already have a template. The thing I wanted to manage was data growth. 

Would you suggest a site collection for each project using a managed path thus potentially separate content databases or at least managed better or subwebs in project site collections.

Thanks for your help so far. Always appreciated!